# Triple Integral Over a Ball

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, volume

How do I compute the following:

$\iiint _V (x^{2n} + y^{2n} +z^{2n}) dxdydz$ where $V = \{x^2 +y^2 +z^2 \leq 1\}$?

Comment: you might want to consider spherical cordinations

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: spherical coordinates, but I do not understand where if any conditions I would need to impose on n would be.

Answer (score 1):

Due to symmetry

$$\iiint _V (x^{2n} + y^{2n} +z^{2n}) dxdydz
= 3\iiint _V z^{2n} dxdydz\\
= 3\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \int_0^1 r^{2n}\cos^{2n}\theta \>r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi
 = \frac{12\pi}{(2n+3)(2n+1)}
$$

Comment: The OP writes:  "there are no restrictions on $n$."  So is your solution valid when $n = -1/2$ or $-3/2$?

Answer (score -1):

Your question as it stands is likely incorrect.  Are you really interested in the cases where $n<0$, for instance??

Assuming $n \geq 1/2$, and using symmetry:

$$8 \int\limits_{x=0}^1 \int\limits_{y=0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int\limits_{z=0}^{\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}} (x^{2 n} + y^{2 n} + z^{2 n})\ dx\ dy\ dz = \frac{12 \pi }{4 n (n+2)+3}$$,

which is the same as @Quanto's later answer.  (Though somehow mine is downvoted.)

Comment: V is the ball of radius 1 and there are no restrictions on n

Comment: Strange to see downvote on this one and upvote on the other! This answer at least recognizes the issue. Even I think the question is incorrect as is or at least needs a clear mention on the definition of $n$. We will end up with multiple solutions for different bounds on $n$ and some may be quite difficult too... for example $n = -1/2$.